# Android Studio inspections

Tags: android-studio

I spent about an hour disabling all the inspections I don't want in Android Studio. Then I closed the IDE. Later I reopened it and all the yellow inspection warnings were back. But then if I disabled one of those many inspections, they all turned off again.

What is going on here? Is this a bug or something I did wrong?

What is the right way to tell Android Studio that, for a particular inspection, I never ever want to see it again under any circumstances for any project?

Answer (score 0):

i think this case cause your computer device is not working properly.
you can try File - Invalidate Caches / Restart - Invalidate and Restart